# Advanced Font Metrics in WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts, fontmetrics

Is there a way in .NET WinForm to obtain advanced font metrics?
I'd need to be able to determine the following programatically:

- Underline thickness
- Underline position
- Strikeout thickness
- Strikeout position

I was able to obtain a lot of information through interop (ex: GetCharABCWidthsW) but they are not sufficient.  These are the only infos I have yet to find a way to obtain.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to call [GetOutlineTextMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144906(v=vs.85).aspx), which will return a [OUTLINETEXTMETRIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162755%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) structure, which contains a bunch of members, including `otmsStrikeoutSize`, `otmsStrikeoutPosition`, `otmsUnderscoreSize` and `otmsUnderscorePosition`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  Thank you!